# How to remove an element from any list object while iterating through <c:foreach> tag in select tag in JSP?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, foreach, jstl

Sample code in JSP:

```jsp
<select> 
  <option value="0">Select</option> 
  <c:forEach items="${list}" var="someList">
    <option value="${someList.value}">${someList.displayText}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

list object coming from Spring controller stored in model object.

Now `someList.value` and `someList.displayText` both the values are the same.

Example:

```
[iphone,samsung,lenovo,motog,oneplus]
```

I want to remove iphone from this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove the item in the `c:forEach` tag but you can use `c:if` tag to filter 'iphone' from the options.

```jsp
<select> 
  <option value="0">Select</option> 
  <c:forEach items="${list}" var="someList"> 
   <c:if test="${someList.value != 'iphone'}">   
    <option value="${someList.value}">${someList.displayText}</option>  
   </c:if>
  </c:forEach> 
</select>
```